# Search taxonomy terms with node_search_execute()

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I tried to use [node_search_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_search_execute/7) to search nodes. So far, running the function is easy. I noticed that there was a `$conditions` parameter from the documentation of [hook_search_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7).

Is there a way to extend the search function to also search for taxonomy terms?
Simple friendly pointers to guide me to do fast and complete node search are also welcomed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure it would be wonderful if there was somewhere you could go and people would just write your code for free based on a terse specification, but this isn't it :) If you have a specific question about an error or problem you're having with your own development please do ask it, but make sure you include the code you're using, error messages, generally what you've tried already. Please see the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: It is possible to answer this question, even if it is not showing any code. It is asking if it is possible to implement a feature. I am going to answer it.

Comment: Thank you, kiamlaluno. Clive was correct; my original question was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the only missing part is the form field that should allow the users to select the taxonomy terms used from the nodes they are looking for. The code used from Drupal 7 (and Drupal 8) is still looking for the corresponding values in `$form_state['values']`.

If you look at the code used by [node_search_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_search_validate/7), the form validation handler added by [node_form_search_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_form_search_form_alter/7), you will notice the following lines.

```
  if (isset($form_state['values']['term']) && is_array($form_state['values']['term']) && count($form_state['values']['term'])) {
    $keys = search_expression_insert($keys, 'term', implode(',', $form_state['values']['term']));
  }
```

If you then look at the code used by [node_search_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_search_execute/7), you will notice the following lines.

```
  if ($query->setOption('term', 'ti.tid')) {
    $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid');
  }
```

Effectively, the functionality of searching those nodes that use specific taxonomy terms has not been removed; it has been hidden to the users who don't have anymore a way to tell the Node module to which taxonomy terms they are interested. This seems rather unintentional; probably the feature was supposed to be completely removed, but the submitted patch removed just the code for the user interface. I cannot find the related issue opened on Drupal.org, and I cannot say if my supposition is correct.

Until the code in `node_search_execute()` and `node_search_validate()` is not changed, all you need to do is adding the form fields in the search form, keeping in mind that the Node module is looking for `$form_state['values']['term']`. (In other words, the form field added for selecting the taxonomy terms should be in `$form['term']`.)

If, and when, that code is removed, adding that form field would not have anymore any effect.
Drupal doesn't allow a module to alter how a module integrates with the Search module. As a matter of fact, Drupal uses [hook_search_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_info/7), but no `hook_search_info_alter()`; if you would want to extend how searching a node is done (for example, by adding more options), you would need to alter the page callback assigned to search/node and search/node/%menu_trail. See [search_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_menu/7).

> [image: Drupal 6]

> [image: Drupal 7]